# Mixing pragma omp parallel for with SSE code: How to reset FPU?

Tags: c, sse, openmp

For image processing, I have an openmp-parallized loop running through each line of the image. Inside the loop I'm using SSE intrinsics:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int y=0; y<=img->height; y++ ) 
{
    [SSE Code]
}
```

I need to use _mm_empty when switching from SSE to FPU code. My understanding is that *each* cpu being utilized by openmp needs to execute _mm_empty.

My current code is obviously wrong:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int y=0; y<=img->height; y++ ) 
{
    [SSE Code]
}

_mm_empty();
```

Only one CPU will have it's FPU re-initialized.

The best solution I came up with so far has a performance penalty:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int y=0; y<=img->height; y++ ) 
{
    [SSE Code]
    _mm_empty();
}
```

This will call _mm_empty for each loop iteration. I'm expecting OpenMP to create a thread pool with about as many threads as CPUs available and divide the work between them. Having for example an image with 720 lines and 4 CPUs, this will end up in _mm_empty being executed 720 times, instead of the required 4.

Is there any concept in OpenMP for defining cleanup-code, executed by each thread? Something like

```
#pragma omp parallel for on thread exit( _mm_empty(); )
for( int y=0; y<=img->height; y++ ) 
{
    [SSE Code]
}
```

Or is there a way to express this with other omp concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was just about the execution of an instruction in each thread, then the standard `omp parallel` pragma should do just that:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int y=0; y<=img->height; y++ ) 
{
    [SSE Code]
}

#pragma omp parallel
_mm_empty();
```

Or combined together

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for( int y=0; y<=img->height; y++ ) 
    {
        [SSE Code]
    }
    #pragma omp barrier    //maybe, maybe not?
    _mm_empty();
}
```

But the actual problem you are facing is the fact, that you cannot be sure that this actually executes the `_mm_empty` on each and every core that the previous loop used. You are only guaranteed to get it called in each thread after its loop (and with the barrier after all threads finished their loop), but the OpenMP runtime (or the OS) is free to schedule threads wherever it wants and whenever a reschedule occurs. But a sensible runtime/OS should indeed care for the threads to get assigned to specific cores and stay there, maybe you could even adjust that somehow with some OpenMP or OS function.

But you know what, you probably don't need this `_mm_empty` madness at all. Keep in mind that `_mm_empty` is only needed when using *MMX* instructions, which were kind of a predecessor to *SSE* (with only 64 bits instead of 128) and used the same registers as the *x87* FPU. But *SSE* brings its own set of registers along with its own status and control flags. So *SSE* doesn't interfere with the "classical" FPU in any way and there isn't any synchronization neccessary. So if it is really only *SSE* operations that you're using and not *MMX* (i.e. you only ever worked with `__m128(i)` types and never with `__m64` types), then just forget about `_mm_empty`.